# Asp.net NHibernate CPU performance after upgrade

Tags: asp.net, sql, nhibernate, memory, cpu

Has anyone else had CPU spikes after switching over to NHibernate?

We switched to using NHibernate about 2 years ago. Since then we've had issues with the server running using the CPU near 60 - 80. We also had issues with the server running out of memory.

Weve consistently been told to optimize our query. Which we did with only limited success. It wasnt until I recently upgraded from NHibernate 2.1 to 3.2 that we finally saw an improvement in the CPU. It dropped from a 60 percent average to about 30 percent. I was amazed, I was told by many who consider themselves experts that upgrading NHibernate would only produce limited improvements if any at all.

My question is ... Has anyone else noticed CPU spikes with NHibernate nd have they seen any improvement after doing a major version upgrade. And last, why exactly is the new version performing so much better? I know NHibernate 3 has a lot better support for linq and about 70 percent of my queries use Linq, so my guess is that may be part of the reason I'm seeing better performace.

Also, does anyone have any ideas how I can optimism NHibernate to produce even better CPU performance other than upgrading the dlls which I have already done.

I'm currently running NHibernate 3.2 and fluent NHibernate 1.2 upgraded from 2.1 and 1.0 respectively.

Comment: Is the DB and website on the same sever?

Comment: Also is this SQL server?

Comment: Windows Server 2003, DB on seperate server, SQL Server 2005. The DB server is relatively stable, no CPU spikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have been told the same as I am about to recommend, but I urge you to look at all  possibilities and discount them.

`Weve consistently been told to optimize our query` - Suspicions always lie with either the  SQL generated by the ORM or the amount of time the DB takes to execute the query. This is sound advice and you must disprove this by using the following methods.

First I would set up a [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) on the live database server that runs for a week. Once this is done you may find that you get suggestions on indexes or SQL related issues.

Secondly I would fire up [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) on my development box and run some stress tests against heavily used pages or pages that have a lot of database trips to see what is going on behind the scenes with NHibernate. NHProf will give you advice about various problems including; select n+1, unbounded results, large number of rows returned, queries with too many joins etc. Again this tool is invaluable to bridge the gap between SQL server and your code.

Hopefully after this exercise you will have ideas on how to fix certain issues, introduce caching  OR if you find you don't have any items to address give you valuable feedback that you can then post to the NHUser group.

After all if you think about it tens of thousands of users use NHibernate. I have used NHibernate myself for several years and subscribe to the NHusers group and I have not seen the CPU spike issue before. Always it turns out to be either;  the SQL generated, the database is under pressure or large recordsets being hydrated

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check into the profilers and sql traces. I haven't had the CPU spike issues on other servers we host. Just this one, the difference between this server and other ones is that the other ones have about 20 sites using NHyrbinate, this one I am talking about has about 510 sites using NHybrinate (and they all use shared code). Basically same code, different design for each site.

Comment: Rippo, I run into a problem when firing multiple Ajax Requests simultaneously. Each of these has a session created for it. Is this bad practice? If so, could you recommend a solution? (I have a question posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615216/moving-from-ef-to-fluent-nhibernate-memory-leaks-architecture